# Elasticsearch autocomplete using nGram, results order

Tags: elasticsearch

I implement autocomplete with the nGram filter, and everything works fine.

my problem is the suggestions returned seem to be in arbitrary order.

for example, I have a field called "id", they seem to be some numbers like "1000", "45100231", but are stored as string. when I type in "10", I hope to see "1000" comes first then maybe "102000", etc. so the ideal suggestion order I want is: the matching part in prefix comes first, then the middle, then suffix. e.g. "1000">"2101">"1110". If the matching parts are all in the beginning, just sort by the next digits. e.g. "1000" > "1011" >"10200"

I've been reading lots of posts about elasticsearch sorting but found no strategy that really works. anyone got any idea? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way I see is keep autocomplete tokens in 3 fields:
1st field keeps prefixes (using edgeNgram)
2nd field keeps only middle word ngram parts (but I think this requires custom filter)
3nd field keeps only suffixes

so for a value `12345` it generates next set of tokens:

- prefixes: `12, 123, 1234, 12345`
- middle: `23, 34, 234`
- suffixes: `2345, 345, 45`

when you have such index, you could use bool filter with matching against this 3 fields, but with different boost factor, for example you boost prefixes ^10, middle ^1 and suffixes ^0.1

I believe the result must be acceptable.

**UPDATE**

for you case only with numbers, I think it's better to use `script_score` from this http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-function-score-query.html and manually check in mvel or javascript, if it's prefix, middle or suffix, but you should keep just raw_id in separate field.

Comment: I have numbers and letters actually. multi-fields seem to be the general solution for sorting and I'm doing that now. although it can't fully meet my need, at least it's better than before. Thanks for your advice!